# Windows Phone 8.1 XAML Image inside ToggleButton adds mystery padding

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, togglebutton

I'm working with a toggle button and rather than show text I want to show an image so I have this:

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="true" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="0" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Icons/phonebutton.png" Stretch="None" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
</ToggleButton>
```

I have the transform to make the image a bit smaller so it's "inside" the button instead of filling it.

However, no matter what I do the button has a large padding around the image, even though the image itself has no margins or padding. I've set margin=0 on everything but the ToggleButton insists on putting space around the image, so the button is larger than it needs to be and cuts off inside the grid row it's in (which has a height="*")

I want the toggle button to "shrink" to fit in the row but still show the full image inside ...

while typing this the autosuggest found this link [ToggleButton does not fill the area(windows phone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215579/togglebutton-does-not-fill-the-areawindows-phone) and by adding the style PhoneTouchTargetOverhang it does look better but then cuts off the image at the bottom unless I add negative padding to the togglebutton.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following margin to an image of 512x512:

```
<Image Source="/Assets/award4.png" Stretch="None" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="-100,0,-100,0">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

And it fits centered